# Evenly spaced grid dynamic content

Tags: css

I'm going to have a grid of `<div>`s that are dynamically generated.  Each `<div>` will be the same width.  I want to evenly space them across their container.  And I want them to space 3 across, and then start again on the next line.  However, the final row may only have 1 or 2 `<div>`s in it, but they need to remain in the same 'grid spacing' as the above rows.

Basically, I want table type spacing, without using tables :)

Here's some example html.  The below would occur on 4 rows, with the final row only having 1 item

```
<div id='container>
     <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
    <div class='item'>Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {
   width:600px;
}
div.item {
   width:180px;
}
```

I had tried the method at the bottom of [this page](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) but it fails when there's only 2 items in a row, because it puts the second item all the way to the right

Comment: Please don't prefix questions with tags. There's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 33%; /* basically 100 divided by however many items per row */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* to include the border dimensions (if any) */
}                           /* in the defined width of the element */

.item:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #aaa; /* aesthetics, just to see the individual items */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RPdt/1/).

References:

- [CSS `box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: This is close, but the problem is, the content of each Div is 180px wide.  So when you make each box 33%, it adds all this space to right of each Div.  So they're evenly spaced, but not across the width of the entire container.  There's still large margin between the 180px content of the last one in each row, and the remaining container with

Comment: that doen't work cause now, even though they're evenly spaced, the left most and right most content are not at the farthest left and right edges, because they're centered within their respective containers

Answer (score 0):

David Thomas's answer works, and is very elegant. The essential things you were missing were the 'float: left' and the 33% width, to ensure that each div always occupies 1/3rd of the container, regardless of the container's size.

Another way you can do this is to use a fluid grid system like the one that comes with [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

This lets you build a fluid grid structure without messing with the CSS. You just specify rows and columns of different percentage-based widths, for instance:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div>
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div>
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div>
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div>
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
    <div class="span4"><div class="item">Content</div></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrBbD/

NOTE: This demo is responsive, so you'll probably have to make the "result" panel wider in order to see the divs laid out in the 3x4 pattern.

Comment: I don't think David's answer does work (unless Im missing something.  See this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/7RPdt/3